# Set inner value for multidimensional array

Tags: php

What I want is that if I have `array('B2WGUR0276 ','TMT Steel')` and once its last value is true then set its last value to be true for all the same combinations of `('B2WGUR0276 ','TMT Steel')`.

$for_quantity sets true or false for the 3rd element in inner array

```
<?php
    $b=array
    (array('B2WGUR0276 ','TMT Steel','10','false'),
     array('B2WGUR0276','TMT Steel','5','true'),
     array('B2WGUR0276','Jindal JSW ','10','false'),
     array('B2WGUR0276 ','TMT Steel','10','false')
    );
    $f=array(array('B2WGUR0276 ','TMT Steel'),array('B2WGUR0276','Jindal JSW '),array('B2WGUR0276 ','TMT Steel'));
    foreach($b as $key=>$keys) {
        if($for_quantity=='true'&&in_array($f,$b)) {
            $b[$key][3]='true';
        }
    }

?>
```

output that is **updated array $b should look like**:

```
$b=array
    (array('B2WGUR0276 ','TMT Steel','10','true'),
     array('B2WGUR0276','TMT Steel','5','true'),
     array('B2WGUR0276','Jindal JSW ','10','false'),
     array('B2WGUR0276 ','TMT Steel','10','true')
    );
```

Comment: sounds good. now how the last value going to be updated to  true and what is tried till now by you?

Comment: i have used in_array and then foreach loop to set the value for $b[$key][3]='true' @Anant

Comment: put your code effort here and we will tell you how to correct it

Comment: i have put in edit @Anant

Comment: Is not if($for_quantity='true'&&in_array($f,$b)) should be if($for_quantity=='true'&&in_array($f,$b))

Comment: note that you have suffix spaces in the first column of the data. I suppose those are typing errors? And why in your desired output is there still one entry with false?

Comment: Oh you removed the quotes around false and true and now you added them again?

Comment: because i want true only for ('B2WGUR0276 ','TMT Steel'). this combination @trincot

Comment: I was talking about the spaces and the quotes...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Given the array *$b*, you could use this:

```
$match = array_flip(array_map(function ($row) {
    return end($row) === 'true' ? $row[0] . "|" . $row[1] : "";
}, $b));
foreach ($b as &$row) { 
    $row[count($row)-1] = isset($match[$row[0] . "|" . $row[1]]) ? 'true' : 'false';
}
```

After this code *$b* will be as you want it to be.

See it run on [eval.in](https://eval.in/611043).

Comment: it sets true for this combination also array('B2WGUR0276','Jindal JSW ') @trincot

Comment: because it is different from ('B2WGUR0276 ','TMT Steel'). @trincot

Comment: can you explain how you did this for exactly ('B2WGUR0276 ','TMT Steel'). @trincot

Comment: Sure, the first loop concatenates the first two values to `'B2WGUR0276|TMT Steel'` and puts that in a new array (the same for any other rows). So you have `array('B2WGUR0276|TMT Steel', ''B2W99999|Otherstuff', ....)`. Then it flips the keys with values, so you get: `array('B2WGUR0276|TMT Steel' => 0, ''B2W99999|Otherstuff' => 1, ....)`. This flip also silently makes every of these values unique. This array is then a lookup array for the second loop.

Comment: what if i have multiple records and select a particular value ?@trincot

Comment: I am not sure what you mean?